# Prove that there is no integer power of $2$ that is the result of a reordering of the digits of another power of $2$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

> Prove that there is no integer power of $2$ that is the result of a reordering of the digits of another power of $2$.

**Attempt:** Say we are working with $2^k$, with $n$ digits.

If we reordered it and got another power of $2$, then the new number must be of $2^{k-3}, 2^{k-2}, 2^{k-1}, 2^{k+1}, 2^{k+2} , 2^{k+3}$.

However none of these numbers are congruent $2^k \text{mod 9}$, we've reached a contradiction.

Unless if we could put the zero in front to shorten the length of the original number, which is still a case I am working on...

**Attemp 2:** I thought in supposing, in order to obtain absurdity, that there is indeed an integer power of 2 which is the result of a reordering of the digits of another power of 2.

Let $2 ^ m$ be the power equal to the reordering of the digits of power $2 ^ n$; for $m, n$ nonnegative integers.

Let's suppose that $m$; that is, we do not consider application identity as a possible reordering. We can then consider m and n positive, since the only solution with one of these nulls would be $m = n = 0$, for the power $2 ^ 0 = 1$.

Comment: $2^{600}$ has 16 zeros. hope you like trying.

Comment: I don't think the original problem is taking into account that weird case you mention.

Comment: @URL Are you allowed to position zeros at the front to change the length of the number in base 10? That's what I answered with my attempt.

Comment: I've seen this problem before, and adding zeros at the beginning was not permitted. You do end up with an interesting problem by permitting this, but I don't think it's in spirit of the original.

Comment: Also, not a lot is known about the decimal expansions of powers: I don't think it's even known if every large enough power of $2$ has any subset of digits. So, this might not be answerable with today's mathematics. Either that, or there's a very ingenious argument, like the$\bmod9$ one.

Comment: @URL See my update. I don't know if it helps so much